# "the dns server is not a valid ip address" error

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns

I today I tried to set google's dns server (8.8.8.8) as my dns but I can't. when I click OK a popup comes out saying "the dns server 8.8.8.8 is not a valid ip address", I'm wondering why, I always used that on other networks. any idea?

I'm on windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are attempting to enter an IPv4 address into your IPv6 configuration. Try the following addresses:

- 2001:4860:4860::8888
- 2001:4860:4860::8844

Source: [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#important_before_you_start)

Comment: oh that was so stupid -.-